# unresolved external symbol (Find out which *.dll visual studio wants (?) )

Tags: visual-studio-2012, dll

I am required to compile various code on a windows machine using Visual Studio 2012.

However, build fails with three similar errors:

```
1>Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static void __cdecl DimServer::start(char const *)" (__imp_?start@DimServer@@SAXPBD@Z) referenced in function _main

1>Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall DimService::DimService(char const *,int &)" (__imp_??0DimService@@QAE@PBDAAH@Z) referenced in function _main

1>Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __thiscall DimService::~DimService(void)" (__imp_??1DimService@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
```

I thought that maybe Visual Studio needs to use a *.dll so I specified in the Project's properties under "Linker/Input/Additional Dependencies" all *.dll four *.dll files I have for this project and gave the path to the respective folder in "VC++ Directories/Library Directories".
However the output the was, that the *.dll files can not be read.

I don't know what to do with this error, maybe I'm on the wrong track.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I believe the dll has to be located in the `PATH` environment variable or application directory.

Comment: Did you write the `DimServer` and `DimService` classes?

Comment: When you built the DLL, you also got a LIB file.  The import library for the DLL.  You need to add this LIB to your project's Additional Dependencies linker setting.

Comment: A.E. Drew: No, those are not by me.

Hans Passant: This was it. I think it dawns on me that a *.dll is the compiled form of a library *.lib, is that so?

Matthew: yes, after adding specifying the *.lib it would only run with the *.dll in it's proper place.

Thank you very much. Building worked now and I can start to work on this thanks to you.
I#d like to vote for your responses but I think comments can't be voted on. At least i don't see how.

Comment: No line breaks in comments? that sucks